# Problem with YouTube Data Api PlaylistItems: list. Why video id duplicates in pagination?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to get list of all videos in a playlist. I am using request to the API https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems with parameters part=contentDetails, maxResults=50, playlistId=UUTSq8e7ERF1u-dr8l5WWGoQ, pageToken=*** But here is the problem: the same video appears on different pages on pagination.

I am trying to do this action several times but some videos always duplicates. I even try to do all request in Postman step by step just if there is error in my code but result is the same.
[[This is a problematic screenshot of playlistItems results using postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISl4S.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkClG.png)]

I hope to get all the playlists. Duplicate video ids will cause me to lose data. I hope to get an answer to solve this problem

Comment: Some videos of the playlist you mentioned are unlisted, so [we are unable to reproduce the issue](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2454863/raw/main/verifyNoDuplicatedVideosIdsInYouTubePlaylist.py?inline=true). Please provide (if possible) a playlist involving the issue not requiring authentication, otherwise we can't at all help you.

Comment: Where do I get a playlist of questions that don't require authentication

Comment: and videos I upload that are not public